# What is the difference between codes in line 4 in the following two programs? The first one prints 5 but the second one prints 15

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

```
s = "azcbobobegghakl"
count = 0
for char in s:
    if char == 'a' or char== 'e' or char== 'i' or char== 'o' or char== 'u':
        count += 1
print count


s = "azcbobobegghakl"
count = 0
for char in s:
    if char == 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u':
        count += 1
print count
```

Comment: the second one always evaluates to `True`

Comment: `if char in 'aeiou'` would be more pythonic... (for the variant that works up here).

Answer (score 0):

Non-empty strings will evaluate to `True`, therefore `or 'a'` will be the same as doing `or True`:

```
>>> bool('a')
True

>>> bool('')
False
```

If you wanted to count the vowels, then you could use regular expressions:

```
import re

s = "azcbobobegghakl"
l = re.findall('[aeiou]', s)
print(len(l))

# Returns: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

`char == 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u'` will evaluate as
`(((((char == 'a') or 'e') or 'i') or 'o') or 'u')`. Since any string other than the empty string will evaluate to `True`, your expression is the same as evaluating `char == 'a' or True`, which will be always `True`.